# Exchange of info between class

Tags: scala, class

I have to link severals objects to each other with the help of their UIDs so I come up with this first code that doesn't compile then I get this solution that I don't understand.

- Why we need a companion object in order to refer a class to another ?

```
import java.util.UUID
def generate = UUID.randomUUID()

//DOESN'T COMPILE, cannot resolve BigBrand.id
//case class BigBrand (name : String, id : UUID = generate)
//case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand_id: UUID = BigBrand.id, id : UUID = generate)

//SOLUTION ?
object BigBrand {
  case class Id(value: UUID)
}
case class BigBrand (name : String, id : BigBrand.Id = BigBrand.Id(generate))

object Outlet {
  case class Id(value: UUID)
}
case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand_id: BigBrand.Id, id : Outlet.Id = Outlet.Id(generate))

val tutu=BigBrand("tutu")
val toto=BigBrand("toto")
println(s"BigBrand id : ${tutu.id}")
println(s"BigBrand id : ${toto.id}")
val tutu1=Outlet("tutu1",tutu.id)
val toto2=Outlet("toto2",toto.id)
println(s"Outlet id : ${tutu1.id} linked with : ${tutu1.big_brand_id}" )
println(s"Outlet id : ${toto2.id} linked with :${toto2.big_brand_id}" )
```

Comment: Does each instance of `BigBrand` have a different id, or is it the same for all instances of `BigBrand`?

Comment: What do you mean by _refer a class to another_?

Comment: all must have different id, this is for discrimate each instance. Each instance of BigBrang, with a unique uid, must be linked to a instance of Outlet with also a unique uid

Comment: It seems what you want can be solved at the value level and not type level. You only need to do this: `final case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand_id: UUID, id : UUID = generate)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the phantom type pattern as shown below.

```
import java.util.UUID
def generate = UUID.randomUUID()

case class Id[A](value: UUID)
case class BigBrand (name : String, id : Id[BigBrand])
case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand_id: Id[BigBrand], id : Id[Outlet])

val tutu=BigBrand("tutu", Id(generate))
val toto=BigBrand("toto", Id(generate))
println(s"BigBrand id : ${tutu.id}")
println(s"BigBrand id : ${toto.id}")
val tutu1=Outlet("tutu1",tutu.id, Id(generate))
val toto2=Outlet("toto2",toto.id, Id(generate))
println(s"Outlet id : ${tutu1.id} linked with : ${tutu1.big_brand_id}" )
println(s"Outlet id : ${toto2.id} linked with :${toto2.big_brand_id}" )
```

Here is an evidence that the type test is working.

```
scala> Outlet("hoge", toto2.id, toto2.big_brand_id)
                            ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Id[Outlet]
        required: Id[BigBrand]
                                      ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Id[BigBrand]
        required: Id[Outlet]
```

Comment: that way it is working fine, I think it solve the probleme and answer the problem of the "why" as well => bcz type definition should have been written that way in order to avoid the compilator to be confused

Answer (score 1):

This is the original code that fails:

```
case class BigBrand (name: String, id: UUID = generate)
case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand_id: UUID = BigBrand.id, id: UUID = generate)
```

The reason this fails is that (as per comments) each `BigBrand` has its own unique `id`. So when you create `Outlet` you must provide the `id` for a specific instance of `BigBrand`. `BigBrand.id` (if it existed) would be a constant for all `BigBrand` instances.

There are two ways of dealing with it, both of which require you to create an `Outlet` using `Outlet(name, big_brand)`.

The first method is to put the `BigBrand` instance in the `Outlet` rather than just the `id`:

```
case class Outlet(name: String, big_brand: BigBrand, id: UUID = generate) {
  def big_brand_id = big_brand.id
}
```

The second method is to pass the `BigBrand` instance when creating the `Outlet` and extract the `id` from that:

```
case class Outlet private(name: String, big_brand_id: UUID, id: UUID)

object Outlet {
  def apply(name: String, big_brand: BigBrand): Outlet =
    Outlet(name, big_brand.id, generate)
}
```

The best option is probably a hybrid of the two:

```
class Outlet private (val name: String, big_brand: BigBrand) {
  val id = generate
  def big_brand_id = big_brand.id
}

object Outlet {
  def apply(name: String, big_brand: BigBrand): Outlet =
    new Outlet(name, big_brand)
}
```

This requires a `BigBrand` to be provided when the `Outlet` is created, and makes `name` and `id` and `big_brand_id` visible while `big_brand` is private.

Comment: I don't think we need to use a companion object for resolve this issue that, since the comment and your answer I have identified as a compilator confusion. Thank for your help !